# How can I visualize a revolving multi-year KPI with unique monthly targets in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax, visualization, powerquery, kpi

I need help developing an approach for a line chart that visualizes actual sales against a monthly KPI sales goal over 24 months.

We have an annual sales goal, tracked until completion for two years at a time. Every month for the 1st year of the goal, we are supposed to achieve 4.0% of the goal. In the second year, the monthly goal shifts to 4.3%.

2021 goal: $1,000,000 in sales, due on 1/1/2023

2022 goal: $2,000,000 in sales, due on 1/1/2024

The dashboard visual needs to understand that it is looking at a goal that began in any X year, and then visualize the calculated monthly targets for 24 months until the goal's due date 2 years later. The goal amount cannot be hardcoded, it varies by team and can be shifted throughout the 2 year period based on certain factors so it's already a calculated measure [Annual Goal].

I've gone in circles thinking DAX, Power Query, Data model relationships, but I hit a wall every time. It seems like I need to group the data in 24 month increments but I don't know how. I've also looked at merging the goals in the Query editor with the raw data, but that duplicates the goal values and makes them difficult to plot. I can't figure out a data model relationship because there isn't a clear connection between the raw sales numbers that are tied to actual dates and the goals table tied to any given base year.

Goal table

```
Goal % | Goal Raw           |  Month    |   Year
4.0%   | Sales Goal*.04     |  January  |  Year 1
4.0%   | Sales Goal *.04    |  February |  Year 1
etc       etc
4.3%   | Sales Goal*.043    |  January  |  Year 2
4.3%   | Sales Goal *.043   |  February |  Year 2
```

Sales Table

```
    Sale     | Date             |  Month    |   
    $10000   | 10/15/2021       |  October  |  
    $11000   | 10/15/2021       |  October  |  
    $9500    | 10/15/2021       |  October  |
```

My end visualization would be based off of a table like this:

```
Sale    |   Sale % of Goal  |  Month Target Goal %    | Month   | Year 
 $1000  |   1%              |   4.0%                  | October | 2020
 $1000  |   1%              |   4.0%                  | October | 2020
 $1000  |   1%              |   4.3%                  | February| 2021
 $1000  |   1%              |   4.3%                  | February| 2021
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have a measure that gives you the `[Annual Goal]` for whatever year you select. I presume that that measure can be filtered by some slicer `Year` which will return the goal for the correct year (starting point).

Let's also assume that you have some sort of table with the calendar which you can use as the X-Axis of your line chart.

You can then create 2  measures to be used on the line chart:

```
//Measure 1
Annual Goal Cumulative = 
  VAR _year = SELECTEDVALUE(YearSlicer[Year])
  VAR _x_month = SELECTEDVALUE(Date[date])
  VAR _no_months = DATEDIFF(DATE(_year,1,1), _x_month, MONTH)

  VAR _pct_target = IF(_no_months <= 12, 
         _no_months * 0.04, 
         0.48 + (_no_months - 12) * 0.043)
  
  RETURN IF( _no_months >=0 && _no_months <= 24, 
     [Annual Goal] * _pct_target, 
     BLANK()
  )

//Measure 2
Sales Cumulative =
  VAR _year = SELECTEDVALUE(YearSlicer[Year])
  VAR _start_date = DATE(_year,1,1)

  VAR _x_month = SELECTEDVALUE(Date[date])
  VAR _no_months = DATEDIFF(_start_date, _x_month, MONTH)

  RETURN IF( _no_months >=0 && _no_months <= 24, 
     CALCULATE(SUM(sales[Sale]), 
        sales[Date] >= _start_date && 
        sales[Date] < EOMONTH(_x_month, 1) + 1 //watch out for the last day of month edge cases
     ),
     BLANK()
     )
```

Plot these 2 measures on a line chart and you should see the progress of sales against the annual target spread over 24 months.

Comment: This is fantastic, thank you, I implemented it and it started working right away. If I can ask you - how would adjust this to work on a Fiscal Year basis, as in 24 months starting from October, rather than a calendar year? Would I just need to update the DATE function to DATE(_year-1, 10, 1)?

Comment: Yes, just adjust your start date accordingly, the rest should hold true.